# hover not working properly

Tags: html, css

When I copied some necessary codes to `jsfiddle` it works correctly but it is not working in my website.

My key problem with Tab menus like `Our Rooms, Our Gems` are not working perfectly when I hover there.

[this is the site in which hover is not working correctly](http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/)

[this is working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3jjm/)

**Edit**

I think the main problem is difficult to understand. So I'm giving a hint. Just change `#tabs li a` with `height: 200px;` then you'll see the pointer is not hovering over the text but below the text.

Comment: What should be happening on hover?

Comment: Hover doesn't change anything neither in the website nor in the fiddle. I see both `text-decoration:none`?

Comment: @Paddyd whole text is not getting hover

Comment: Nothing is happening in jsfiddle for me.....

Comment: in jsfiddle it is hovering to all text but not in website

Comment: @C-Link I got the culprit wait...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want a pointer on the entire tab, so you need to modify your class like this on `line 1877` in `template.css`

```
#tabs li a {
    color: #E79D34;
    display: block;
    font: 20px/50px calibri;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It works in your fiddle because the CSS is NOT normalized, in your website, CSS is normalized.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E3jjm/1/) of not working fiddle

The issue is your `h1` tag having class `logo`, it is overlapping your tabs

[image]

Comment: @C-Link What do you want to happen on hover, the only difference I saw was of pointer in the fiddle and the actual website

Comment: @C-Link It totally works for me :) just change the code where I told you to, just replace that totally in the source

Comment: @C-Link That's weird, I used firebug and I can get pointer over whole tab

Comment: @C-Link Same here, wait I'll attach screens

Comment: @C-Link It's the h1 tag containing the logo is causing this issue as it is overlapping the tabs for some reason which I cannot make out from firebug, if you remove the h1, it will work well

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
a:hover, #tabs li a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is something that overwrites your `:hover`. It is either an `!important` keyword or another definition of `:hover` after the one you try to fix. Review your code or try using `!important` in the hovered block.

Answer (score 0):

coz
 you have made
a
{text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover
{text-decoration:none;
}

there is no difference in a & a:hover

change something in a:hover

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style, this will work

```
#tabs li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

you can also do it this way:

```
#tabs li a,
#tabs li:hover,
#tabs li a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Did you understand my problem?